# create a new csv file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, file-io

I am trying to write my dictionary in a sf file, here is how i am doing it:

```
with open(path3 + 'extend.csv', 'w') as fw:
    for key1, value in d.items():
        fw.write(value +',')
    fw.write('\n')
fw.close()
```

The thing is that I get an extra comma at the end of each line. How can I prevent this form happing in the first place?

Comment: As a side note, `dict` item order is not maintained. This approach is fine if you don't care what order you're putting those values into the csv file, but I think for most people they do care. Either iterate over specific dict keys or switch to a list for `d` (which maintains order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `",".join` to do this. Also, you can directly access the values using `d.values()`, so you don't really need to do iterate over the dict and then extract the values.

So essentially, your code can be simplified to:

```
with open(path3 + 'extend.csv', 'w') as fw:
    fw.write(",".join(d.values()))
    fw.write('\n')
fw.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `csv` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
import csv
with open(path3 + 'extend.csv', 'w') as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(d.values())
```

Comment: Can I substitute some computed double value for d.values() here? What's the origin and structure of the referenced d.values() in this context? A dictionary?

Comment: Yes, writer.writerow works with a list of strings or numbers are argument (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) or in newer versions with an iterable providing the values for the rows (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow). `d` is  the dictionary of the code snippet in the questoin.